# C# custom object invalid cast

Tags: c#, casting

I'm trying to cast my object like below:

```
public interface IObjectComparison
{
    object GetPropertyValue(string property);

}

public class MyObject : IObjectComparison
{
    public object GetPropertyValue(string property)
    {
        ...
        return (object)...;
    }
}
```

And then

```
MyObject mo = new MyObject();
IObjectComparison imo = (IObjectComparison) mo;
```

When casting from `MyObject` to `IObjectComparison`, I'm getting an **InvalidCastException**. Why ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Once GetPropertyValue in MyObject is public, this code works just fine..

Comment: [Works as expected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hlNlWJ), no cast exception when the interface is properly implemented.

Comment: Check MyObject  constructor, if you have in your code.

Comment: And the cast itself is not needed there, as `MyObject` implements `IObjectComparison` it's completely valid to assign `MyObject` object to `IObjectComparison` variable without casting.

Comment: Are you sure that this is your actual code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: The problem was the "using" instruction was referencing the bad namespace

Answer (score 1):

You do not need cast here at all.Just use:

```
MyObject mo = new MyObject();
IObjectComparison imo = mo;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:

```
public interface IObjectComparison
{
    object GetPropertyValue(string property);
}

public class MyObject : IObjectComparison
{
    public object GetPropertyValue(string property)
    {
        return new object();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyObject mo = new MyObject();
        IObjectComparison imo = (IObjectComparison)mo;
    }

}
```